# Running Django Model Query for more than one value for same Field

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to know how can we run queries from Django Model if we want to retrieve more than one value for same field

For Example This is my Model

```
class Ball(models.Model):
    Ballname  =  models.CharField(max_length=8,primary_key=True)
    Ballcolor =  models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I am trying to get All Balls of Red and White Color

```
dataset = data.filter(Ballcolor="red", Ballcolor ="white")
```

But I get an error saying same field cant be used more than once. How do I get about getting this data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `in`

```
dataset = data.filter(Ballcolor__in=['red','white'])
```